# Does synchronizing method prevents objects fields being updated?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized, locks

Consider the following class.

```
public class Counter{

  private Lock lock = new Lock();
  private int count = 0;

  public int inc(){
    lock.lock();
    int newCount = ++count;
    lock.unlock();
    return newCount;
  }

  public int incBy2() {
      syncronized(this){
      count+=2;
      return count;   
      }
}
```

Now Thread T1 calls inc() method and T2 calls incBy2(). Is there a race condition here?
or will T2 lock `this`, thereby preventing inc method to call to `lock.lock()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitor on an object doesn't have any effect on the rest of the object. Acquiring the monitor on an object doesn't do anything to stop any threads from modifying fields of that object. Acquiring a lock only prevents other threads from acquiring that lock.

When you write

```
class Foo {

    public void doSomething() { 
        synchronized(this) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

you are better off writing

```
class Foo {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void doSomething() {
        sychronized(lock) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The first version doesn't do anything more for you than the second one. The only difference between these two versions is that in the second one it doesn't affect the locking on doSomething if other objects acquire the monitor on the Foo object itself (so the lock is encapsulated within the object and can only be acquired by threads calling the doSomething method).

Answer (score 1):

There is a race condition. You are essentially synchronizing on two separate objects.  Both threads can enter `inc()` and `incBy2()` critical sections at the same time.

Comment: when I syncronize on `this`, I am implicitly blocking other threads to access the fields which in this case is a lock object.

Comment: @brain: no. John is right. acquiring the monitor on this doesn't do anything to deny another thread access to lock.

Comment: @brainstorm as Nathan said, but to add.  You are blocking other threads from accessing critical sections, not fields.  Synchronizing on `this` says, any caller that tries to `synchronize` on `this` will have to wait until I complete.  As you can see, since there is no `sychronize(this)` in `inc()` then another thread doesn't have to wait.